# Node.js interpreter returns Function Not Defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I am trying to learn back-end and front-end languages.
Recently, I have been trying to implement Derek Banas' "OOPGame [C# Tutorial no.8]" in JavaScript. However, the code returns 'GetAttackResult not defined' when I run it using the node interpreter.

How can I fix it?

Here is my code:

```
class Warrior
{
    constructor(name, health)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.health = health;
    }

    Attack()
    {
        let attackValue = Math.round(Math.random * 50);
        return attackValue;
    } 

    Block()
    {
        let blockValue = Math.round(Math.random * 10);
        return blockValue;
    }
}

class Battle
{

    StartFight(warrior1 , warrior2)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (GetAttackResult(warrior1, warrior2) == "Game Over")
            {
               console.log("Game Over");
               break;
            }

            if (GetAttackResult(warrior2, warrior1) == "Game Over")
            {
                console.log("Game Over");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    GetAttackResult(warriorA, warriorB)
    {    
        let warA_attack = warriorA.Attack();
        let warB_block = warriorB.Block();

        let dmg2warB = warA_attack - warB_block;
        warriorB.health = warriorB.health - dmg2warB;

        if (dmg2warB > 0)
        {
            console.log(`${warriorA.name} attacks ${warriorB.name} and deals ${dmg2warB} damage.`);
            console.log(`${warriorB.name} has ${warriorB.health} health.\n`);

            if (warriorB.health <= 0)
            {
                console.log(`${warriorB.name} has died and ${warriorA.name} is victorius`);
                return "Game Over";
            }
            else return "Fight Again!";
        }
     }
 }

Main();
function Main()
{
    let apple = new Warrior("Apple", 3000);
    let microsoft = new Warrior("Microsoft", 3000);

    let hi = new Battle();
    hi.StartFight(apple, microsoft);
}
```

And my output on running it:

```
[Running] node "i:\JSPractise\tempCodeRunnerFile.js"
i:\JSPractise\tempCodeRunnerFile.js:4
    let apple = new Warrior("Apple", 3000);
                ^

ReferenceError: Warrior is not defined
    at Main (i:\JSPractise\tempCodeRunnerFile.js:4:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (i:\JSPractise\tempCodeRunnerFile.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.42 seconds
```

Note: I am learning JS from 'The Eloquent JavaScript' book, and I follow it closely. Also, I use 'Main()' to define the entry point b'cuz I come from a C/C++ background and I find it convinient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `GetAttackResult` is a *method*. That means you access it as a property on an instance created via `new Battle` (often that will be `this`). It isn't a standalone function.

So for instance (see comments):

```
StartFight(warrior1 , warrior2)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (this.GetAttackResult(warrior1, warrior2) == "Game Over")
        //  ^^^^^
        {
           console.log("Game Over");
           break;
        }

        if (this.GetAttackResult(warrior2, warrior1) == "Game Over")
        //  ^^^^^
        {
            console.log("Game Over");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Some languages let you leave `this.` off references to fields and methods (Java, C#). JavaScript does not.

Comment: *If you see the second set of `^` pointing to something without `this.` hit refresh. Editing error, doh!*